# Getting user input (ie. an account number, checkedboxes, checked radiobuttons) from a form textbox and checkboxes and grab the files from db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> Main thing i am trying to do is get the account number, and which checkboxes they checked, so that it will grab the correct files from the database that correspond with the month and years they have selected.

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="my-container">
                <label class="acct-text" for="AccountNumber"> Step 1 - Enter Account Number :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account-number" placeholder="Account Number">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="year" for="Year">Step 2 - Select Statement Year(s) :</label>

            <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
                @foreach (var year in ViewBag.TenYears)
                    {
                        <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkBoxYear"> @year</label>
                    }
            </div>
            <button id="selection"  class="select-all-years">Select All Years</button>

        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p><label class="month-text">Step 3 - Select Statement(s) Month :</label></p>
                <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container">
                    @foreach (var month in Model)
                    {
                        <label><input id="month" type="checkbox"> @month.MonthName</label>
                 
                </div>
                <button id="selection" class="select-all">Select All Months</button>
            </div>

            <p><label for="AccountNumber">Step 4 - Select Delivery Method :</label></p>
            <p><label><input type="radio" name="filedecision" id="download" /> Download Statemtents</label></p>
            <p><label><input type="radio" name="filedecision" id="email" /> Email Statemtents</label></p>
            <input type="text" class='txbx' hidden="hidden" />
            <p class="message" hidden="hidden">* To send to multiple recipients, separate the email addresses using a comma "," </p>
            <p class="message" hidden="hidden">* Statement(s) will be delivered via FMBSECURE</p>

            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit" value="Retrieve Statements" onclick="DisplayLoadingDiv();" id="main-content-submit" style="">

    </form>
```

> Here is home controller I know this isn't the right way of doing things but i am trying to make my dbcontext and don't really know where to put it.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MyDatabase db = new Mydatabase();
            ClientStatement_Inventory clientStatement_Inventory = new ClientStatement_Inventory();

            StatementViewModel statementVM = new StatementViewModel();

            statementVM.accountNum = clientStatement_Inventory.accountNum;
            statementVM.statementDate = clientStatement_Inventory.statementDate;
            statementVM.statementMonth = clientStatement_Inventory.statementMonth;
            statementVM.statementYear = clientStatement_Inventory.statementYear;
            statementVM.statementPath = clientStatement_Inventory.statementPath;


            return View(statementVM);
        }
```

> Here is my ViewModel. These are the things that I need to be able to know what is checked or not so that it will grab those files.

```
public class StatementViewModel
    {
        public string accountNum { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime statementDate { get; set; }
        public string statementYear { get; set; }
        public string statementMonth { get; set; }
        public string statementPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can grab the account number with javascript like so:

```
var accountNumber = $("#accountNum").val();
```

> And then you can use an ajax call to pass that to your controller like so:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Home/ExportFile',
                data: JSON.stringify({ acctNum: accountNumber }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                       
                        });
                    }
                    
                },
            });
```

> Didn't write some code for brevity but I think you should get the jist

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed.